# VBA Excel code to Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a code below that I created for Excel. I am now trying to apply it to Access. There are changes that were made to the code that should have made it compatible for Access but it's still giving me an error. I'm not understanding what this error is and what to do about it:

```
Option Compare Database
Public Function OldMaturity(term As String, invoicedate As Date, days As Long) As Date

Dim d As Date
Select Case term.Value
    Case "STD":
        OldMaturity = DateAdd("y", days.Value, invoicedate.Value)

    Case "BONM":
        d = DateAdd("y", days.Value, invoicedate.Value)
        OldMaturity = DateAdd("m", 1, DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 1))

    Case "EOM":
        d = DateAdd("y", days.Value, invoicedate.Value)
        OldMaturity = DateAdd("y", -1, DateAdd("m", 1, DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 1)))

    Case Else:
        OldMaturity = CDate("99/99/9999")
End Select
End Function

Public Function NewMaturity(invoicedate As Date) As Date
Dim val1 As Long
Dim val2 As Long

val1 = invoicedate + 120
val2 = DateAdd("m", 1, val1)
NewMaturity = DateSerial(Year(val2), Month(val2), 1)

End Function
```

This is the error that's showing:

[image]

Comment: `term` is a String - it doesn't have a `Value` property.  Should just be `Select Case term`

Comment: I cannot see the image, but I'm guessing there is an issue with this part `val1 = invoicedate + 120` because you are adding a date defined variable to an integer which doesnt work. if you are trying to add 120 of some unit to a date, use the `DateAdd` function like you are doing in the following line.

Comment: You need to take `.Value` out of `term.Value`, `days.Value` and `invoicedate.Value`. These are Value Types now, not Ranges.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative version of your `NewMaturity` function:

```
Public Function NewMaturity(ByVal invoicedate As Date) As Date
    Dim d As Date
        d = DateAdd("m", 1, DateAdd("y", 120, invoicedate))

    NewMaturity = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 1)
End Function
```